# Choosing a method for algorithmic problems - is it an art or science?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms, backtracking

I've been doing lot of programming challenges lately (such as on leetcode.com) and often find myself in a situation when I cannot pick a method for solving a problem. I stuck with questions like - should I use brute force or greedy search would work better or maybe dynamic programming would do the job? Then I start coding a solution just too find out it does not work and I have to pick another method.

I wonder if there is a way to restate the problem in some abstract way and from there to see what solution technique would work for it?

Comment: Problem solving is open-ended.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus hard to argue with that. What I'm looking for is a guidance on how to recognise that a problem can be efficiently solved with a method or reject a method for a given problem.

Comment: 1) Experience. There are tons of approaches, but with some experience, you would "feel" when they are applicable. 2) Prove correctness **before** coding. "start coding a solution just too find out it does not work" should be a rare exception. And understanding why it fails can point towards solution. 3) Try a number of small examples. Usually, you can find some patterns from them, which point towards solution. 4) For greedy/dp: write your recursive function on the paper: it simplifies writing it as a code, and it's much simpler to prove that it's correct when it's in front of you.